# how to apply the some array method to a filter search in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algorithm, search, data-structures

I am building a search functionality for fun using `react` and i have the following data structure:

## data.js

```
export const data = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "first_name": "James",
    "last_name": "Wattson",
    "gender": "M",
    "age": 43,
    "country": "USA",

  },
...
```

## List Data

[image]

## search query result

[image]

## codes

```
const App = () => {

  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
  const filterKeys = ["first_name", "last_name", "gender", "age", "country"]

  const handleOnChange = (event) => {
    const filterQuery = data.filter(value => value.first_name.toLowerCase().includes(event.target.value))

    setQuery(filterQuery);
  }

  const tableResults = query.length > 0 ? query : data;

  return (
    <div className="form">
      <div>
        <input placeholder="search..." onChange={handleOnChange}/>
      </div>
      <div>
        <Table data={tableResults}/>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};


export default App
```

My search functionality work fine but is only limited on the first_name data as input.

How can i possibly update the `const filterQuery` variable logic using the `.some() array method` to be able to add filters based on the array `filterKeys` strings, which are additional keys that i could search for their values.

Goal: being able to search for the values of each keys, including: first_name, last_name, gender, age, country. the codes above can only search for first_name values

something like this

```
const filterQuery = data.filter(value => filterKeys.some(key => value[key].toLowerCase().includes(event.target.value)));
```

but this does not seem to be correct... because it crashing on the chrome console tab while typin. the error `Uncaught TypeError: value[key].toLowerCase is not a function`

Comment: @trincot sorry i have updated the post to include that and the error i am seeing in the console of the chrome browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes you get `typeof value[key]` Number, Number do not have method `toLowerCase()`, so you need use:

```
const filterQuery = data.filter(value => filterKeys.some(key => (value[key] + "").toLowerCase().includes(event.target.value)));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you get this error:

> value[key].toLowerCase is not a function

...it means that `value[key]` is not a string (maybe `null` or `undefined` or numeric?). This is the case with the "age" property, as it seems to be numeric. To deal with this situation silently, chain a call to `.toString` and make all property lookups conditional, using the optional chaining (`?.`) operator:

```
value[key]?.toString()?.toLowerCase()?.includes(event.target.value)
```

Comment: found the solution from this website:
https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-typeerror-tolowercase-is-not-a-function#:~:text=The%20%22toLowerCase%20is%20not%20a,the%20toLowerCase%20method%20on%20strings.

i was missing `toString()`... `.toString().toLowerCase()`

Answer (score 0):

You `handleOnChange` function could be like this:

My solution does not use `some` array method, just another way to get what you want (do not need the `filterKeys` as well)

```
  const handleOnChange = (event) => {
    const term = event.target.value;
    const filterQuery = data.filter((record) => {
      return (
        Object.values(record)
          .filter((r) => !Number.isInteger(r))
          .filter((r) => r.toLowerCase().includes(term)).length > 0
      );
    });

    setQuery(filterQuery);
  };
```

`Object.values(record)` will return all the `value` of record object, after that, you need to use `filter` to find which record has `value` contains `event.target.value`.